# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in ajax-jquery

Tags: jquery

I am sure there is a bracket missing somewhere here or an extra , or ;.
I am getting unexpected token or unexpected identifier errors!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      setInterval("ajaxd()",10000);
    });
      varJackpot =0;
      varPrevious=0;
    function ajaxd(){
      $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "getJackpot.asp?dx=<%=skinid%>",
       data: "",
       success: function(data){
         varJackpot =data[0];
         varPrevious =data[0];   
       }
    }) 

    $("#counter").flipCounter(
        "startAnimation", // scroll counter from the current number to the specified number
        {
        number: 5, // the number we want to scroll from
        end_number: 1024, // the number we want the counter to scroll to
        easing: jQuery.easing.easeOutCubic, // this easing function to apply to the scroll.
        duration: 5000, // number of ms animation should take to complete
        onAnimationStarted: myStartFunction // the function to call when animation starts
        //onAnimationStopped: myStopFunction, // the function to call when animation stops
        //onAnimationPaused: myPauseFunction, // the function to call when animation pauses
        //onAnimationResumed: myResumeFunction // the function to call when animation resumes from pause
    })
    function myStopFunction() {
    varPrevious = varJackpot;
    });
    }
</script>
```

The getJackpot.asp call returns a single number. Example:

```
url: "getJackpot.asp?dx=7",
```

will return something like 12345.95

Unexpected token: line 39

This whole thing is based on [FlipCounter](http://bloggingsquared.com/jquery/flipcounter/) from this link. Any pointers will be appreciated muchly.

Comment: You need to close the parenthese of your `$.ajax` function.

Comment: I edited based on suggestion @Abhijit Mazumder and uploaded again as there is one more error that just wont go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not closed the ajax call :)

```
$.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "getJackpot.asp?dx=<%=skinid%>",
                   data: "",
                   success: function(data){
                     varJackpot =data[0];
                     varPrevious =data[0];   
                   }
                } **)**
```

:)

Comment: Thanks Abhijit. Doing that has now thrown another error on line 36 "Unexpected token }, which is the line just after "onAnimationResumed"

Comment: I marked this as answer as it got me on the right track and solved the problem.

Comment: remove the following bracket :) `function myStopFunction() {
    varPrevious = varJackpot;
    }**)**;`

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I completed the work. I will be posting the completed project for anyone to use shortly. Hopefully everyone can use a live jquery based odometer style counter to display anything like site hits or charity collections in real time.